# What exactly is a mobile station?

Tags: mobile, telecommunication

I searched and found a lot of confusing answers to what exactly a mobile station is. The answers range from a simple mobile device to a PABX. Could somebody clarify this for me?

Comment: This may highly depend on the context. I'm afraid, this question is kind of meaningless without a context. I also doubt this is on-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

I Found your answer on this [GSM module](http://electronicsforu.com/resources/what-is-gsm-module/) article.

A mobile phone and Subscriber Identity Module (SIM) together form a mobile station. It is the user equipment that communicates with the mobile network. A mobile phone comprises of Mobile Termination, Terminal Equipment and Terminal Adapter.